# Load relations for a query result separately

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Let's say we have two models **Book** and **Author**. The Book model defines a relationship to get the author:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id','id');
}
```

If we want to get all of the books that were published in 2000, along with their authors, we can do this:

```
$books = Book::with('author')->where('publication_year', 2000)->get();
```

Now what if we want to return the unique Authors who published in 2000 *separately* from their Books? Let's say Bob published three books and Sally published two books. We'd have one collection that included the 5 books without their authors, and another collection that included Bob and Sally once each.

This is the closest I've gotten (this is a simplified example and may contain typos):

```
$books = Book::with('author')->where('publication_year', 2000)->get();
$authors = $books->pluck('author')->unique('id');
//this part is bad:
foreach ($books as $book) {
    unset($book['author']);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, or do I have to set up a manual JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereIn` as:

```
$books = Book::where('publication_year', 2000)->get();

$authors_id = $books->unique('author_id')->pluck('author_id');

$authors = Author::whereIn('id', $authors_id)->get();
```

Comment: Ah, this approaches the problem from a different direction than I had been thinking. I like it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get IDs of authors who have written books in 2000, you could use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Author::whereHas('books', function($q) {
        $q->where('publication_year', 2000);
    })->pluck('id');
```